# "Invisible" unicode characters being printed as symbols in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Unicode characters with integer codes 1-10 are control characters that are "invisible", ie when printed should not display as a glyph. However, in Jupyter (tested in version 6.x and 7.x beta), when I have a pandas series containing these characters, they are displayed as symbols. For example 7 displays as a phone symbol. In the examples below I include firstly a screenshot from Jupyter followed by a code block containing the raw text, in case your system displays the text differently from mine:

[image]

```py
pandas.Series([chr(7)])
```

```
0    
dtype: object
```

The character being displayed is [U+260E](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+260E), while I would expect [U+0007](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0007).

If I don't put this character in a series, it prints correctly:

```py
chr(7)
```

```
'\x07'
```

[image]

Also, if I run this code outside of Jupyter, it prints as an invisible character, which is also correct:

```py
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.Series([chr(7)])
0    
dtype: object
```

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent this incorrect behaviour? The result is that it shows incorrect characters in my notebook, which makes my work look incorrect.

Some other system information:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- Python: 3.9.5 (but this happens on any Python)
- Jupyter: 7.0.0a8 and 6.5
- Pandas: 1.4.2

---

**Edit 1**. Some other characters that get printed are as follows:

```py
pandas.Series(range(10)).apply(chr)
```

```
0     
1     
2     
3     
4     
5     
6     
7     
8     
9    \t
dtype: object
```

[image]

Notably I believe #5 is [U+2234](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2234), which is not 2 code points before the phone symbol.

Comment: what do you get when you display other control characters?

Comment: Other strange characters. Arrows and such.

Comment: it might be helpful to show the mappings for the other characters. perhaps there's a pattern here.

Comment: Updated with additional mappings.

Comment: The source code for https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/ demonstrates how to draw a mapping of all supported 8-bit encodings for character codes 128-255, but I never before saw any need to map the regular ASCII codes in the range 0-127. It should not be hard to adapt for this task, though. Then if this is a supported 8-bit encoding, you should be able to find the right one. Perhaps first [edit] to show the HTML source within Jupyter; I'm vaguely guessing this could simply be an HTML problem.

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow seems to strip out invisible characters, which means that screenshots are actually the clearer way to convey this information.

Comment: We'd still need to understand how you are running Jupyter in your browser. If your browser is set up to use some funny encoding for displaying Jupyter, the problem is entirely on your side, and unreproducible.

Comment: If you do a "view source" on that Jupyter output pane, what do you get?

Comment: In what format would you like me to share the output? If I copy the raw characters it seems they get stripped out by StackOverflow, but I suspect you aren't happy with just a screenshot.

Comment: Copy/paste of a (small, relevant snippet of) "view source" would be ideal. If that doesn't correctly represent what's there, can you provide a hex dump? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: For what it's worth, I updated https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/ to also display codes 0x00-0x1F but that didn't reveal anything useful.

Comment: If you put the view source text into a code block starting and ending with triple backticks, I don't think anything will be stripped out by StackOverflow.  If they are, then we'll have to settle for a screen shot; it would be better than nothing.